# Angular create a external link with query params

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an app where I have a user address and I want to make a feature that when I click on the user address it opens google maps with his address.

I managed to make the app open google maps gut for the search params it literally pastes {{ this.customer.address }} instead the value...

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Html component:

```
        <mat-list-item *ngIf="customer.address" (click)="openExternalUrl()">
          <mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined" matListItemIcon>home</mat-icon>
          <div matListItemTitle class="property-name">Address:</div>
          <div matListItemLine>{{customer.address}}</div>
        </mat-list-item>
```

component TS:

```
getSingleCustomer() {
    const id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    this.customerService.getSingleCustomer(id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.customer = data;
       
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error', error);
      });
  }

openExternalUrl(): void {
    window.location.href='https://maps.google.com/?q={{this.customer.address}},{{this.customer.city}}';
  }
```

Comment: seems the data is not binded in your URL, instead pass values in your function as parameters and then  append to URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use JS's string interpolation :

```
window.location.href=`https://maps.google.com/?q=${this.customer.address},${this.customer.city}`;
```

The moustache `{{...}}` used by angular for interpolation can only be used in templates.

Comment: thank you it works :) and idea how to open this in new tab?

Comment: use `window.open("https://", "_blank");`